# What use is initUserDefaultOptionalParameterPackage in EWL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, enterprise-web-library

I'm using EWL and I have an `EwfPage` and when I type `partial` in the `Info` class I see:

```
partial void initDefaultOptionalParameterPackage( OptionalParameterPackage package )
```

and

```
partial void initUserDefaultOptionalParameterPackage( OptionalParameterPackage package )
```

I don't really see what they're used for. They also sound similar and I'm wondernig what the difference between them is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both used if you want an optional parameter to default to something other than the default value of its C# data type. There are two significant differences:

- `initUserDefaultOptionalParameterPackage` is called *only* when you are creating an `Info` object for the page; it is not called when the page is requested. If a request is made without a parameter value in the URL, the framework will fall back to the value specified in `initDefaultOptionalParameterPackage` or the data type default.
- You can access `AppTools.User` from `initUserDefaultOptionalParameterPackage` if you meet the conditions specified in the doc comment for `AppTools.User`.

An example of when you might use `initUserDefaultOptionalParameterPackage` is a page that should default to showing information for the currently logged-in user but has a select list or something that lets you look at information for a different user.

Comment: Is `initDefaultOptionalParameterPackage` called only when the page is requested?

Can you provide an example of when `initUserDefaultOptionalParameterPackage` is useful?

Comment: @Sam.Rueby: `initDefaultOptionalParameterPackage` is called whenever an `Info` object is created, whether it is for the current request or not. For your second question, see my edited answer.